User cannot query Bigtable with BigQuery Filtered Data Viewer permissions
I have a dataset in bigquery that has row level access policies that restrict access based on an account id. In order to link a user to an account ID, I add a specific row level access policy.
The policy looks as follows:
query = f"""
CREATE ROW ACCESS POLICY {email_name}{email_suffix}\_{account_id} ON `{table}`
GRANT TO ('user:{email}') FILTER USING (account_id="{account_id}");
"""
bigqueryclient.query(query)

I can see the policy in the bigquery console.
When the user tries to query the table with the following project level permissions:

BigQuery Filtered Data Viewer
BigQuery Job User
BigQuery Metadata Viewer
BigQuery User

The following error is shown:
Access Denied: Table <tablename>: User does not have permission to query table <tablename>, or perhaps it does not exist in location EU.
I tried to assign permissions such as BigQuery Data Viewer which resulted in the row level access policies not being enforced.
What am I doing wrong? Is it about the policies or about the permissions I assign in the project?
